# Как в ElasticSearch сделать поиск по объединению полей?

Tags: elasticsearch, полнотекстовый-поиск

Например, в индексе есть три поля FirstName, LastName, MiddleName. Мне нужно сделать поиск по подстроке в ФИО. Т.е. нужно объединить поля в fullName и сделать поиск по подстроке. Можно ли сделать это на этапе поиска, чтобы не выделять отдельное поле fullName? Использую библиотеку NEST для C#

Comment: Решение: собираем нужные поля с помощью copy_to, при поиске используем MatchBoolPrefix с оператором And